# How check the whether database user mentioned in property file has granted access to all table defined in schema on startup of restful service

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

Rest service: Spring rest
DB: Postgres

Problem definition: In production env, we are getting issues due to lack of permission on the table for the user configured in the property file.

All such issues generally got notified at runtime only.

To Avoid such permission related issues, Is there any out of box way in spring boot which will check whether the user-defined in property file has all the select/delete/insert/update permission on all tables that are created in the schema.

I do understand we can use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate but this only checks datatype, missing table, missing column issues only.

Thank you.

Regards,
Kiran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to handle the situation from spring boot. Finally I reached to conclusion that i can handle it in Database and would grant  permission to the table and sequence created in future too.

Kindly see below URL,

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/

Thank you.